# Construction of Rational Numbers without quotients

Tags: rational-numbers, type-theory

The context is Intensional Type Theory, where quotients are unavailable.
I managed to construct Integers in this way: $\mathbb{Z}:=(\mathbb{N}^+\times\{{+,-\}})+\{{0\}}$, but I can't see a way to construct Rational numbers.

Comment: In what sense are quotients *unavailable*? What stops you from carrying out the construction of quotient fields from integral domains?

Comment: I can't flesh it out into a full answer right now, but the idea is to have a tuple of integer numerator, positive integer denominator and a proof of coprimality. I think you can do a similar construction whenever you have a (decidable?) property (coprimality in this case) that picks out one representative from each equivalence class for quotients in general.

Comment: For quotients unavailable I mean that in my theory I can't construct set and more generally types using quotients; that is more or less the difference between Intensional and Extensional Type Theory. About Potato's idea: thank you that seems a very good construction, I'll try implementing it